# How can i declare a value that will change with target value

Tags: c#

How can i declare a value that will change with target value. like;

```
bool isInFrozen = true;
bool frozen = isInFrozen;
    
print(frozen); // Prints True

isInFrozen = false; // Value changed

// Im wanting to print isInFrozen's changed value
print(frozen); // But still prints true
```

Comment: Take a look at *ref* docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frozen` needs to be a `ref`erence

```
bool isInFrozen = true;
ref bool frozen = ref isInFrozen;

Console.WriteLine(frozen); // Prints True

isInFrozen = false; // Value changed

Console.WriteLine(frozen); // Now prints False
```

For more details on c# references, take a look [at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)